# multi value autocomplete using Jquery UI not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i am using jquery Ui for multi value autocomplete and it's working fine but after first suggestion selected and for next request it sending entire text box value it's not splitting up  eg: suppose in autocomplete text box i typed ' A ' it give suggestion like ' ABC ',' ACB ' and some more values, now 
i will select ' ABC ' and  autocomplete text box look like '  ABC ,     ' and i will type ' B ' hear it should send only ' B ' to server instead it sending ' ABC , B '

hear what i want is : after selecting first time suggestion i should send a request that present after ' , ' how can i do this

this is my code

```
$(function() {

function split( val ) {
     return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}

function extractLast( term ) {
    alert(term); 
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#authorList" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/catalogue/getMultiAuthor.action',
                dataType: "json",
                data:{"term":request.term},
                success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (term) {
                        return {

                           label: term
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus 
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input 
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item 
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end 
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
```

});

Comment: [Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) does work as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the complete term because of this : `data:{"term":request.term}`

Just change this to `data:{"term":extractLast(request.term)}`